# "Username", "user name" or "user-name"

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, compounds, computing, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

In computer science, you should have a *username* or a *user name* or a *user-name* and a password to be able to log into the system.

Which one is the correct spelling?

Comment: what about log onto the system?

Comment: I believe the correct wording for the logging based alternative would be "log into the system".

Comment: @bernk Since you can both log into a system and onto a system both would be fine.  Most sites have you log in, though some systems use log on since you are using the system (on it) not maintaining or modifying the system (in it).  I doubt most people would even notice the difference.  Sign vs Log is covered at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/logging-in-or-on

Comment: Similarly, "file name" vs "filename".

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The OED gives ‘username’ and has three citations, from 1971, 1997 and 2007, in support.

Comment: OED = "Oxford English Dictionary". For those who don't know (I didn't).

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you can provide a link to the same in OED, if possible. IMHO, It would add more value to the answer.

Comment: IMHO = "In My Humble Opinion". For those who don't know (I didn't).

Comment: @garnet Not exactly OED but here is the Oxford Dictionaries (Lexico) link https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/username
For the difference between OED and Oxford Dictionaries see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexico#Lexico_vs._Oxford_English_Dictionary

Answer (score 96):

The correct spelling in this case is username.

- The **username** is the (usually unique) thing you type in with your password, for example: *bobsmith66*.
- The **user name** is the name of the user, the user's real life name, for example: *Bob Smith*. User name is sometimes used for username, but occasionally it makes a difference, so be clear and avoid the ambiguity. (Better still, use **full name** when you want them to enter *Bob Smith*.)
- **User-name** is a variant of username, but this is rarely used if ever.

Comment: Instead of "Full name", many software titles (such as Microsoft Windows and Active Directory) use "Display name", btw.

Answer (score 52):

Obligatory Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=username%2Cuser+name%2Cuser-name&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cusername%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuser%20name%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

In case the link breaks again: *username* is much more common these days; *user-name* is not used at all.

Comment: This supports the answer I was going to give. "Username" and "User Name" are both relatively common; "user-name" is rare.

Comment: I get a completely different graph when I click the link

Comment: user-name is used, it is just an order of magnitude smaller than the smallest tick on your graph.

Answer (score 35):

I've seen both "*username*" and "*user name*" used widely. Both are acceptable. As far as I know, techies mostly prefer "*username*". "*User-name*" just seems awkward.

Comment: Very often in development I see another variation, *UserName*. I assume this comes from "User Name" being contracted. It can lead to confusion when both *username* and *userName* are found throughout documentation.

Comment: However I'd argue that *user name* is the user's birth certificate name in real life, rather than the unique string for logging into the system.

Comment: @Hugo, As a software developer, I'd argue that "user's name" or "real name" is their real life name.  But software developers sometimes forget who's using the software.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food  As a software developer, I agree "user's name" or "real name" is their real life name, but in addition to "user name". I recommend to avoid the ambiguity and stick to "username" for the unique login ID (and perhaps "full name" for the real name).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Coding style guides apply to code and not the English language, and are irrelevant here.

Comment: @Hugo Not quite. The style guidelines exist *because* the “correct” English word is “username”, not “user name”. In particular, this style guide is regardless of the programming language. The programming language dependent part merely specifies whether you’d write the identifier as `userName` or `UserName` or `user_name` (that is, whether to use camelCase, PascalCase or whats_er_name) but several style guides *additionally* caution that “username” is a single word and should *not* be written as either of the above.

Comment: @Hugo, fair call.  Until I saw this question's answers, I wasn't even aware "username" was a real word.  Or "filename" for that matter.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Searching the MSDN documentation for 'username' and 'filename' refutes your statement. Most common is `UserName` and `FileName`, indicating that the terms the .NET folks consider standard are 'user name' and 'file name'.

Comment: @JHoren Microsoft has never been known for their consistency. However, I apparently remembered the wrong guideline: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx.

Comment: @Konrad: To be fair the core .NET Framework is pretty consistent.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but the table at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#capitalizing-compound-words-and-common-terms could do with updating, as "username" is now generally considered a closed compound noun so shouldn't have a capital 'N'. Not to mention they have two different spellings of  "cancel(l)ed" on the same row...

Comment: Forget that! It's already been raised and can't be changed as it is quoting from copyrighted material. https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6523#issue-342191594

Answer (score 10):

Like most things in language, it depends upon context.

If you are writing a journal for a computer science publication, **username** is acceptable.

If you are writing the user's manual or labeling a field, I would use "**user name**" since the users may or may not be well versed in computer science, and it just feels less complex.

Comment: No, as @skst mentioned, the correct general term should be "__user id__".

Comment: @Mark, I have no problem with using "User ID" or "User's identification code" when referring the the user's identification.  I am, however, very big on consistency.  If the development teams uses "UserName" as a field name and variable name inside the code, reference these elements in technical documents, there is a better than even chance that this phraseology will leak through to the end user.  In that case, I'd prefer to use the same term they used so there won't be a document referring to the same item by two terms.

Comment: @MarkHurd in UNIX, at least, your username and userid are different. John Smith's username might be "smithj" and his userid be 1043.

Comment: @slim: Yes, I was thinking of Windows where there is a concept of a user's name, a user id and, very much behind the scenes, but most similar to the Unix uid, the user's sid.

Comment: Users need not be familiar with computer science to be expected to be familiar with end-user oriented general computer terminology, like "username" or "email" or "password", etc.

Answer (score 9):

In terms of computer science , *username* is mostly used as a standard. I have always used that.

Answer (score 2):

The O.E.D. often defines words merely because they're commonly used, regardless of their correctness. (For example, I don't consider "LOL" or "ginormous" to be words.)

I realize that it is often used to describe "the thing you type in with your password," but that is more correctly called the user ID since it is not the actual name of the user.

In my opinion, it's a compound noun and the correct spelling is "user name" as in "the name of the user." Just because we can delete the space between two words doesn't mean we should, although plenty of compound nouns do. Language evolves, of course, and it's just as likely that we're in the middle of this word's evolution. In a few years, I may change my mind and edit this entry.

Comment: You may not consider “LOL” a word but that doesn’t make it less one. Remember, English isn’t a prescriptivist language. Words exist *because they are used*, not the other way round.

Comment: You're right that a "username" is more correctly called a "user id", but I believe that "fight" is lost already and "user name" is _only_ the correct spelling of "the name of the user".

Comment: I'd also point out that "LOL" is an initialism. Again, not a word.

Yes, words exist because they're used, but how much does a construct have to be used before it's deemed a word? And who's the arbiter doing the deeming? These are subjective requirements, and my point was merely that I don't think the O.E.D.'s bar is high enough.

Comment: The OED editors are the arbiters deciding what words go into their dictionary. They [require](http://www.oed.com/public/faqs#qualify) several independent usage examples and evidence it's been in use for a reasonable amount of time. One word may have only a few examples spread over a long period of time, another may gather momentum very quickly, resulting in a wide range of evidence in a shorter space of time. "The idea is that a puzzled reader encountering an unfamiliar word in, say, a 1920s novel, will be able to find the word in the OED even if it has been little used for the past 50 years."

Comment: `"I'd also point out that "LOL" is an initialism. Again, not a word. "` Is lol a word? Is radar a word? What about scuba and laser? Are acronyms really not words? You are correct that the OED records common usage, not "correctness", because there is no official arbiter of "correct" English.

Comment: While _radar_, _scuba_, and _laser_ all started as acronyms (RADAR, SCUBA, and LASER), they've evolved to be the words that represent those technologies. On the other hand, "LOL" isn't a word because people capitalize every letter when they write it and spell it when they pronounce it; they write "LOL" and say "L-O-L" rather than "lol."

Comment: @skst fwiw, I think people are increasingly saying "lol". Just for the lulz, innit?

Comment: @skst: [Documentary](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf97e1HXzlo) that at least two people say "lol" and "roffle" rather than L. O. L. and R. O. F. L. Both are also sometimes written lowercase "lol" and "rofl".

Comment: What can I say, @Hugo? People misspell "their," say "There is some groceries," and punctuate "the '50s" incorrectly, too, but it doesn't make them right (nor, hopefully, does it constitute a trend). ;-)

Comment: @slim: If it's just for lulz, it's okay. We all appreciate irony. :-)

Comment: @skst: Indeed, and there's different levels of "correctness", especially for slang, but especially for internet slang.

Answer (score 0):

In computer terminology use the word "username" and/or "filename", always. For variable/class names in computer coding also use "username/Username" and/or "filename/Filename" and **never** "userName/UserName" and/or "fileName/FileName".

Comment: My answers that I gave here are the most perfect answers you can get on this subject. Read them again and follow the instructions that I have so lovingly offered to you.

Comment: @JayElston: If you don't like an answer, by all means downvote.  But what does lateness have to do with anything?  Not everyone was a member when a question was asked, and I've seen plenty of questions where a late reply did add value to the discussion – for example, [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/what-is-more-appropriate-data-or-information-when-referring-to-facts-about).